# SignalR TypeError: Failed to fetch after deploying to Azure

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to create a small chat app using SignalR. In my backend I am using .net Core 5 and in Frontend, I am using React.
When running in localhost every thing is working fine and there is not any connection error, but when deploying application to live server on azure, signalR don't connect at all because of this error: [image]

I tried to enabling "skipNegotiation" using code below but error does not solved.

```
const newConnection: any = new HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(AppConsts.remoteServiceBaseUrl + '/chat?' + query,{
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets
  })
  .build();
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please tell me where you host your application on Azure web app or Azure VM 's IIS?

Comment: Azure web app @BrandoZhang